# JavaMail getConent after closing folder (folderClosedException)

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, shared-directory

Does anyone have experience with the `Javamail javax.mail.FolderClosedException` ?

My problem is:
I want to read some mails, everything ok. But i've changed my reader class to a more technical class, wich only gets the `Message` Objects.

In a second step i want to make beans. Getting the information like subject is very easy:

```
public void getMail(Message msg) {
   subject = msg.getSubject();
   ...
}
```

Main problem here: `msg.getContent` requires a opened folder...
but my technical reader class gets all the message objects, closes the folder...
after that my business-method `getMail` does the `msg.getContent`

is it possible to do that in that way with a business-class and a technical class, or do i have to setup the mail-beans in the technical class and return a list of them?!

Answer (score 3):

Your problem seems to be that `getContent()` will load the content from the server, as the  JavaMail implementation normally first begins to download the requested information, when you actually need it, e.g. by calling `getContent()`.

You could kind of force to download everything completely before handing over the stuff to your business code. So, instead of handing over the message objects directly you get from your technical class, you can create a copy of them. This forces the JavaMail classes using e.g. an IMAP connection to fully download your message:

```
/* assuming you retrieved 'message' from your folder object */
Message copyOfMessage = new MimeMessage( (MimeMessage) message );
[..]
folder.close();
[..]
yourBusinessObject.getMail( copyOfMessage );
```

But I have to admit I have never tried to access the copied object **after** closing the folder. And also never used this with POP3. But I would give it a try.

Comment: I know this is late but this method works, just tested with IMAP.

Comment: thank you for reporting this as working :) (also late)

Answer (score 1):

How about just passing in the stuff you need, instead of the `Message` instance? Like

```
public void getMail(String subject, Object content, ...) {
   ...
}
```

of course it's not as clean as before, but might do the trick ;)

PS: Für d'IPA, oder hesch die dure?

Comment: PS: shouldn't it be named `setMail` - but dunno.

Comment: Yeah but that's exactly the problem, i don't want a trick... is it possible in a other way? I'm working like your answer at the moment... but i want to change it.

Comment: have you tried doing `message.geContent()` before passing it into `getMail`? maybe, the contents are then cached?